# Get all site collection of a web application using powershell in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to get all collection url and name of a web application and export the values into excel, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Web application URL and CSV File location Variables
$WebAppURL="https://intranet.crescent.com"
$CSVFile="C:\SitesList.csv"
 
#Get list of site collections in a web application powershell
Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL | Get-SPSite -Limit All | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
             SiteName = $_.RootWeb.Title
             Url = $_.Url
             DatabaseName = $_.ContentDatabase.Name }
} | Export-CSV $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It works, thanks.